# How do I find where Java is installed on Windows 10?

Tags: java, windows-10, java-home, appv

I recently installed Java (Java Runtime 1.8.121) to my machine. I need to set up JAVA_HOME and set the variable from the Java folder where it installed.

Everywhere I have looked online says the Java folder should be located in Program files (x86), however, it is nowhere to be found. Its not in program files (x86), not in program files.
I wasn't able to choose a destination when it was installed as Software center was used. It simply completed the installation.

Can someone please help me find where the Java folder is so I can set up JAVA_HOME???!

Comment: Can you execute `java --version` on the command line? If so, try `where java`.

Comment: If he want to set up JAVA_HOME i guess java XXX command will not be available, am i wrong?

Comment: @Wortig possibly. But PATH and JAVA_HOME are separate environment variables, so maybe PATH is set.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-is-installed "as with java -version, this command is only useful if our PATH environment variable points to the bin directory."

Comment: `java -version` will work without `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: This might help: https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/1148677/finding-location-java-home-in-windows-10

Comment: What distribution of Java did you install? AdoptOpenJDK/Temurin (old adoptopenjdk)/ORACLE JDK... ? Maybe post a site from which you downloaded Java. Installations of different JDK's / JRE's can have different paths.

Comment: I think the superuser question might have answered it. I checked Java control panel, which shows that it's actually in C: > ProgramData > App-V > 758738 > 3232234 > Root > VFS > ProgramFilesX86 for some reason.

Comment: Strangely enough CMD did not work - entering "where java" brought back "INFO: could not find files for the given pattern".

Comment: Because its in program data, which is hidden, I can't use it to set up JAVA_HOME. Does anyone know if I can just move the Java folder elsewhere? Straight into my C: Program files x86? Without it messing anything else up?

Comment: Please, use your APP-V client! ...then you (probably) can: `java -version`, `where java`, ...

Answer (score 8):

- [cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where):

  ```
  where java
  ```
- [git bash](https://carlowood.github.io/which/) (same as cmd or):

  ```
  which java
  ```
- [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command):

  ```
  (get-command java.exe).Path
  ```

  - [Superuser: Equivalent of cmd's "where" in powershell](https://superuser.com/q/675837/107659)

Comment: java_home is java_home, but this "solution" considers `%PATH%` only !;)

Comment: when I do "where java" in cmd I just get "INFO: could not find files for the given patterns"

Comment: it means: it is not on/your installer didn't (successfully) modify the `%PATH%` ... App-V: doesn't that mean that you are/use java in a "virtual environment"!? ;) https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5398078e-0956-461c-b9d6-28be15ff0965/appv-50-environment-variable?forum=mdopappv

Answer (score 6):

Open a command prompt

type: `wmic product where "Name like '%%Java%%'" get installlocation,Name`

This command can take a minute to complete. But should return something like this.

[image]

Edit: The benefit of this command, is that it doesn't rely on any system environment variables. It searches for installed programs that have the word 'Java' in the name. It won't return extra files or locations.